# Killing a window without killing the associated buffer

Tags: buffers, window

I have a weirdly specific way I like to organize my windows when working with C, and where emacs opens the compilation window really bugs me. I try to close it and switch another window to the `*compilation*` buffer, but for some reason the `kill-window` command also kills the buffer. Is there a way to avoid this? Or am I just doing this in a really asinine way?

Comment: I don't have a `kill-window` command but try `delete-window`; it shouldn't kill the buffer.

Comment: @amitp no luck, still kills the buffer

Comment: Are you using any sticky buffers, like treemacs or sr speedbar?

Comment: also post the result of C-h v ignore-window-parameters

Comment: @A_P I just had to reinstall my disto, so the settings are pretty much the same as the defaults. `ignore-window-parameters` is `nil`

Answer (score 4):

Start Emacs using `emacs -Q`.  That ignores your init file.

I think you'll see then that `delete-window` (bound to `C-x 0`) does not kill any buffer.

If so then you must be inflicting this pain on yourself.  As the good doctor said, *"Don't do that."* ;-)

Recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit.  You can use command `comment-region` to comment (or, with `C-u`) uncomment the region.  Comment out 1/2 of your init file, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,... to narrow and find the problem.  This is very quick (it's a binary search), but you will need to restart Emacs each time.

(Another possibility is that the buffer has not been killed but you think it has.  Try `C-x C-b` to see if it's still there.)